# Multichannel audio over USB from Android Phone

Tags: android, audio, stream, usb

I'm doing some research on how to stream multichannel audio from an android device to an external DAC.
The receiver has a USB2-B audio input which I would like to stream audio to from the phone.
It seems that Android OS has limited support for USB Audio - but it's more than nothing for a start. I've also read that some apps in this space use their custom driver...

I went through a lot of questions and answers here (and on other sites) but somehow I can't get a proper answer (most of them are super old or just not exactly what I am aiming for...)

So how can I stream an mp4 file with 4-6 channels of audio through the USB to an external DAC? The file is coded with AAC-LC and/or xHE-AAC - so the file itself supports multichannel. The phone is running Android 11.

I've been looking at the [USB-Host mode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host), and [USB Audio](https://source.android.com/devices/audio/usb) website, among several other StackOverflow examples, and also visited [extreamsd.com](http://extreamsd.com/index.php/technology/usb-audio-driver) to see how they did it but not much luck with seeing actual code samples...

Anyone could point me in the right direction or whether it is possible at all and if yes then how?

Thank you

Comment: Did you ever find anything? I am also trying to understand how those players (UAPP, HiBy, Neutron etc.) are able to use the USB audio hardware directly. I assumed it must be via Android's USB Host mode, but then that doesn't support isochronous endpoints for streaming audio so idk.